# How to import a custom font in a RN Expo app

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

I want to import a custom font in my rn app once, and use it in every component. The code that I have come up with it is this:

fontConfig.js:

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

const loadFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({

    "boldfont": require('../../assets/fonts/SpaceGrotesk-Bold.ttf'),
      "regularfont": require('../../assets/fonts/SpaceGrotesk-Regular.ttf'),
    // Add more fonts here if needed
      
  });
};

export default loadFonts;
```

App.js:

```
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import loadFonts from './src/screens/fontConfig';
const App = () => {

   const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadFonts().then(() => {
      setFontsLoaded(true);
    });
  }, []);

 

  return (

    <Onboarding3/>
   
  );
};

export default App;
```

It gives me error saying :
**"boldfont is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsnyc - If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.
If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync."**
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use it:

```
export const CUSTOM_FONTS = {
  GothamBold: require("../../src/assets/fonts/GothamBold.ttf"),
  GothamBoldItalic: require("../../src/assets/fonts/GothamBoldItalic.ttf"),
};
```

And I call useFonts hook while the splashscreen is on.

```
import * as Font from "expo-font";      
const [fontsLoaded] = Font.useFonts(CUSTOM_FONTS);
```